# how can I force the bot to send a message to a specific channel when the user joined the guild?

Tags: discord.py

I tried to get the bot to send a message to the welcome channel when a user joins the guild, but everything I did is not working

bot.py

```
import discord
import config

TOKEN = config.settings['token']

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    channel = client.get_channel(config.channels['welcome'])
    await channel.send(f'Hi, welcome to Pandemonium!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

config.py

```
settings = {
    'token': 'my_token',
    'bot': 'Astarot',
    'id': 3170,
    'prefix': '-',
}

channels = {
    'welcome': 787727303718469633
}
```

Comment: Function get_channel need ID of channel, no name
Instead of this, use: for i in guild.channels:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because the event is not called, to fix that enable `intents.guilds`

```py
# Here I'm enabling default intents (everything apart from members and presences)
intents = discord.Intents.default()

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

[Introduction to intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents)

Also, `on_guild_join` is called when the **BOT** itself joins a guild, not when a user joins a guild, if you want that use `on_member_join` and enable `intents.members`